# How to override compiler options for referenced c++ project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I am using visual stuido 2010.

I have a static library call "common library". This common library is referenced by many other projects. These projects use the common library by "add new reference" (in project properties -> common properties -> add new reference).

All these projects have their special compiler options/predefined macros. Common library needs to conform their settings, or the compilation fails. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

The current solution is: copy a new "common library" project file for each project, and set the options/macros in the new project file. It is very painful.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but have a look at [property sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx). They enable you to specify a set of compiler options and macros that you can add to any project.

Comment: A property sheet can save your time if you have many projects that need to have same propertes. What I want is to override the settings in project file without changing it. They are two different things.

Comment: @Enzo: If the library must match the projects settings, then a copy is the best method.  However, I've never heard of a library that needed to have it's settings match the projectms settings, and that sounds poorly designed.  I'd suggest changing the library to not depend on the project it's linking with.

Comment: The real scenario is, I want the common library to support different windows versions. The interface is the same, but the implementations of some functionalities in common library can be different for different windows versions. So I hope the projects that depend on common library can set the WINVER for common library before compiling it.